# OpenShift Origin - Failed to fetch the file: [Errno 13] Permission denied For ETCD Certificartes

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, redhat, openshift-origin

I am trying to install **OpenShift Origin** using [Ansible playbook](https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible).

I have 3 Master, 3 External ETCD hosts. So while running the playbook, I get the following error:

```
  1. Hosts:    etcd_host1_ip
     Play:     Configure etcd
     Task:     Retrieve etcd cert tarball
     Message:  Failed to fetch the file: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/etcd_certificates-94b5HdP/etcd-dts-etcd-3.fcxlocal.tgz'

  2. Hosts:    etcd_host2_ip
     Play:     Configure etcd
     Task:     Retrieve etcd cert tarball
     Message:  Failed to fetch the file: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/etcd_certificates-liHJ5gz/etcd-dts-etcd-1.fcxlocal.tgz'

  3. Hosts:    etcd_host3_ip
     Play:     Configure etcd
     Task:     Retrieve etcd cert tarball
     Message:  Failed to fetch the file: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/etcd_certificates-A9PENQO/etcd-dts-etcd-2.fcxlocal.tgz'
```

> I have set the following variables in the Ansible inventory file:

```
# Set variables common for all OSEv3 hosts
[OSEv3:vars]
ansible_become=true
ansible_ssh_user=nonroot_user
openshift_deployment_type=origin
```

> On Master `oc version`, gives following info:

```
oc v3.6.0+c4dd4cf
kubernetes v1.6.1+5115d708d7
features: Basic-Auth GSSAPI Kerberos SPNEGO
```

As I understand, when I run the Ansible playbook, these etcd required certificate tarballs are being exported to the `/tmp` path of the host machine form where playbook is being triggered. Since I am running the Ansible with a different user with passwordless sudo access and these tarball files are exported to `/tmp` with `root` access only. Hence I am getting this **Permission denied** issue.

**How can I overcome this problem ?**

> What I have tried so far ?
>
> I have tried to give `chmod -R 777 /tmp` , but this does not work as those tarball files are exported during ansible playbook runtime with root access only.

Any help will be highly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: It would be polite to [link to what I presume is your GH issue](https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible/issues/5635)

Comment: Now I'm torn about whether to speak to the GH issue or here, but anyway: I would highly recommend running ansible at maximum verbosity to see if you can spot the bad assumption it is making: `ansible-playbook -vvvv -i ...all-the-rest... &>ansible.log`

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel thanks for the suggestion, I will try it out and update. I had created the SO question first, since did not get any response, my teammate has posted that GH issue later on the day.

Comment: I am facing the same problem on the "Retrieve etcd cert tarball" task. It went error with the message of unable to create local directories on /tmp folder.
Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got almost the same error as yours. 
In my case, the error happened on the task of "Retrieve etcd cert tarball". 
Error message: Unable to create local directories(/tmp/{Master-hostname}/etc/etcd/generated_certs):[Errno 13] Permission denied /tmp/{Master-hostname}

I executed the deploy-cluster.yaml playbook on my Bastion/Boot node. (This node is separated from other OpenShift cluster node). 
I checked the permission of my OpenShift node (3Master, 3Infra, 3Worker), and they are showing the expected permission as 777. 
But, I noticed the /tmp directory on my Bastion/Boot node was changed to 755 (root:root). Other user can't write this folder. 
During the OpenShift installation, Ansible creates temporary directory (for the etcd certificates) on /tmp. Since there is no permission for other user to write the /tmp, the process terminated. 
(In my case, the Ansible playbook is executed on Bastion/Boot node as Ansible server)

I fixed the problem by giving write permission to Other user by setting it to 777. 
Re-run the deploy-cluster.yaml and it should be fine.

There is still one big question, why the /tmp on my Bastion/Boot node changed to 755. I am sure my /tmp directory was previously set as 777, but it changed (misteriously?) to 755. (which is the cause of the Permission denied)